# Faker get streetAddress throwing ErrorException

Tags: laravel, factory, faker

I'm building a laravel application, and I've created a FakerServiceProvider to populate factories for testing and local dev.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Faker\Factory;
use Faker\Generator;
use Faker\Provider\en_GB\Address;
use Faker\Provider\en_GB\Person;
use Faker\Provider\en_GB\PhoneNumber;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\DeferrableProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

/**
 * Class FakerServiceProvider
 * @package App\Providers
 */
class FakerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider implements DeferrableProvider
{
    /**
     *
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(Generator::class, function ($app) {
            $factory = Factory::create('en_GB');
            $factory->addProvider(Person::class);
            $factory->addProvider(Address::class);
            $factory->addProvider(PhoneNumber::class);

            return $factory;
        });
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return [Generator::class];
    }
}
```

I have created an address factory:

```
<?php

use App\Address;
use App\Country;

$factory->define(Address::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'line_1' => $faker->secondaryAddress,
        'line_2' => $faker->streetAddress,
        'town' => $faker->city,
        'county' => $faker->county,
        'country_id' => factory(Country::class)->make()->id,
        'postcode' => $faker->postcode,
        'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
    ];
});
```

When I try to use this factory I get the following error:
`ErrorException: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method Faker\Provider\Address::streetAddress() should not be called statically`

I have checked the source for the Faker library and there is a streetAddress method [here](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/blob/1fcc3430e86c62e0215a3d29410a45dba9d5a22c/src/Faker/Provider/Address.php#L73)

I have tried calling both `$faker->streetAddress` and $faker->streetAddress()`with no luck. I would expect`$faker->streetAddress`to produce something like` ` or something similar.

Can anyone shed a bit of light on this for me

Comment: What is the purpose of the first code block? The second looks fine, I use the `streetAddress` property in my factories with no problem. How are you using the factory?

Comment: @miken32 it is a service provider to inject a localised instance faker with the providers I need

Comment: Well that doesn’t make things any clearer for me LOL. Can you edit your question to show how you call the factory in your tests? What version of faker does Composer say is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the added providers in the Faker Service Provider fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides direct access of php Faker library.
You just need it this way on your factory

````
    ```php
    'Street_Address' => fake()->streetAddress(),
    ```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).